# "TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function" mobile menu button wont work (trying to fix)

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

I'm getting an error using magento.  I'm using this theme http://demo.magentech.com/themes/sm_igame/

The JavaScript error I get is

> TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
>
> `<anonymous>`  opstrike.com:3849 m.Callbacks/j()  jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
>   m.Callbacks/k.fireWith()  jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 .ready() 
>   jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 J()  jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2

I searched for `TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function` and found there may be a problem with plugins interfering with my code.  So I removed plugins that I wasn't using, but I still have this error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You are loading two different jQuery resources:
`skin/frontend/sm-igame/default/sm/megamenu/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js`
`skin/frontend/sm-igame/default/js/jquery.1.11.js`
Which never is a good practice.

Try to deactivate MegaMenu's jQuery loading somewhere in its preferences / configuration.

Also you might want to run [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) since there might be some other frameworks (such as MooTools etc.) that are *occupying* the `$`-shorthand for jQuery. When visiting you website I figured that other jQuery calls are throwing "... is not a function" error.

You could also try to open the fancybox-overlay with a `jQuery('a > img').fancybox();` instead of `$('a > img').fancybox();` ($ = shorthand for 'jQuery').

Nevertheless a code sample or a link to a page where you use fancybox would be helpul.

---

After I dug a little deeper into your code:
I am not sure why you are using such a large, complex JS-function to manipulate the fancybox-relevant links, image urls, and stuff (`function _SmQuickView()`). This makes it pretty hard to debug since fancybox actually is just a one-liner. Also the `beforeShow` and `afterShow` dependencies could probably be handled easier - if they would have to at all, but I'm not sure what you're up to with this.

I tried to scale browser down to mobile size and made the `.yt-product-detail . popup-btn` visible. And then fancybox using the icon link just works fine.